# EF Inherited class with no parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.7.2

I am having issues pulling data out of a sql database using EF (4.7).

My model looks a bit like this:

```
public class User : MyEntity<User> {
     public User(string userId) : base(userId) {//Some other props}
}

public abstract class MyEntity<T> where T : class
{
    protected MyEntity(string userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        base.Update(userId);
    }
}
```

So the error is pretty obvious, that I need a parameterless constructor on the User. However, as this is a user based system, I have most of the models inheriting from the base class. So this would mean all my classes need a default constructor in it to allow EF to bind to the model. Not really ideal as it mitigates the way the domain model should be constructed.

I have tried putting in a protected constructor on the MyEntity to resolve the issue, but this doesn't seem to get picked up by EF.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Support for entity [types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) was introduced in EF Core.  And EF Core 3 is [supported on .NET Framework 4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/).